# Percentile giving different result for same query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having a problem about the percentiles aggregation in elasticsearch. The aggregations 'valor_medio', 'area_util_media', 'area_total_media' are giving me different results every time I execute this query. The differece between the values aren't big, but I need the values to be the same if the query and the data haven't changed. I'm using the following Query

```
  GET imoveis/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "valor": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "valor_medio": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "valor"
      }
    },
    "area_util_media": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "area_util"
      }
    },
    "area_total_media": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "area_total"
      }
    },
    "imoveis_count": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "_id"
      }
    },
    "ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "bairro.id.keyword",
        "size": 1000000,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "valor_medio": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "valor"
          }
        },
        "area_util_media": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "area_util"
          }
        },
        "area_total_media": {
          "percentiles": {
            "field": "area_total"
          }
        },
        "imoveis_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "_id"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "geohash_grid": {
        "field": "geohash",
        "precision": 4
      },
      "aggs": {
        "centroid": {
          "geo_centroid": {
            "field": "geohash"
          }
        },
        "top_hit": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "tipo_imovel",
                "geometry",
                "id",
                "area_construida",
                "area_terreno",
                "area_total",
                "area_util",
                "bairro",
                "banheiro",
                "cidade",
                "cidade_uf",
                "codigo",
                "condominio",
                "descricao",
                "endereco",
                "garagem",
                "geohash",
                "imobiliaria",
                "isparticular",
                "lista_fotos",
                "nome_corretor",
                "numero_corretor",
                "opcionais",
                "quarto",
                "tipo_negocio",
                "uf",
                "url",
                "valor"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "geo_shape": {
                      "geometry": {
                        "shape": {
                          "type": "polygon",
                          "coordinates": [
                            [
                              [
                                -49.10408,
                                -25.330373
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.11644,
                                -25.466214
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.12262,
                                -25.520756
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.148026,
                                -25.635336
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.167938,
                                -25.685469
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.183731,
                                -25.715786
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.192657,
                                -25.726921
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.203644,
                                -25.734962
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.211884,
                                -25.738674
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.240036,
                                -25.745477
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.251022,
                                -25.746714
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.282608,
                                -25.745477
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.32312,
                                -25.736818
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.345093,
                                -25.726303
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.371872,
                                -25.701557
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.405518,
                                -25.658858
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.442596,
                                -25.599425
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.450836,
                                -25.583943
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.470749,
                                -25.535626
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.477615,
                                -25.510841
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.481735,
                                -25.476133
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.481735,
                                -25.462495
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.480362,
                                -25.453815
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.476929,
                                -25.444515
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.468689,
                                -25.429013
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.450836,
                                -25.410408
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.430237,
                                -25.395521
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.352646,
                                -25.358919
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.218063,
                                -25.306787
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.088287,
                                -25.25898
                              ],
                              [
                                -49.10408,
                                -25.330373
                              ]
                            ]
                          ]
                        },
                        "relation": "within"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "tipo_negocio": "Venda"
              }
            },
            {
              "geo_shape": {
                "geometry": {
                  "shape": {
                    "type": "envelope",
                    "coordinates": [
                      [
                        -49.47322458028794,
                        -25.795102447042222
                      ],
                      [
                        -49.0866431593895,
                        -25.23243168187146
                      ]
                    ]
                  },
                  "relation": "within"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a precision problem, changing it solved the issue.